# I can use selenium only in pycharm but not in gnome-terminal.It only works in pycharm

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm, gnome-terminal

I can use selenium with pycharm but not in gnome-terminal.

ModuleNotFoundError:No module named 'selenium'

is shown when I try to execute(in gnome-terminal) the python file which include the sentence "from selenium import webdriver".

What is the difference between 2 environment?.

Comment: PyCharm is not python environment. It is IDE. When you run your code with PyCharm it adds project folder to `sys.path`. So I guess the problem is that you run scripts located not in the project folder. You may move the script to the project folder. Or add project folder to `sys.path` just like PyCharm does. Or you may create some kind of a launcher located in the project folder so it is added automatically.

Comment: I've been trying to execute the python file(which I've used in PyCharm)with gnome-terminal.So the python file is already in the project folder of PyCharm.

Comment: Probably you have installed selenium only on your pycharm project's virtual environment but not in the global interpreter.

Comment: I've made it after I reinstalled selenium at gnome-terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall selenium in PyCharm and reinstall selenium in gnome-terminal and reinstall selenium in PyCharm.